# Appropriate X.509 settings for OIDC token-signing and token-validation

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, identityserver4, openid-connect

What are the basic requirements for secure X.509 self-signed certificates intended for use as OpenId Connect token-signing and token-validation credentials?

I have an IdentityServer4 project, and I've been experimentally generating certificates with many different options and settings via Powershell's `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command. It seems almost any combination of options are accepted for token-signing and token-validation purposes.

Most of what I find online relates to code-signing, not token-signing, and I've found nothing about token-validation. It seemed like something I'd expect in the reference section of Identity Server's documentation, but they bounced my [question](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1968) as "not a bug," so here I am trying my luck with the general public.

Are there applicable standards, and how do they translate into `New-SelfSignedCertificate` parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following link which appears to be how Brock is creating his certificates.

https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/

Comment: Good find, halfway there! And somebody even posted a [Powershell](https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/#comment-39261) version in the comments.